Non-smooth points of a polydisk
I am wondering why the moment map description of a poldisk is non-smooth. This is not the case for an ellipsoid: The moment image of a 4-dimensional ellipsoid corresponds to a triangle but none of the corners (in the triangle) correspond to non-smooth points. For the polydisk of radii $a_1 > 0$ and $a_2 > 0 $ in $\mathbb{C}^2$:
$$P(a_1 ,a_2) = \{ (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : \pi |z_i |^2 / a_i \leq 1 ,\: i =1,2\}$$
the moment image corresponds to a rectangle with corners at $(0,0), (a_1,0), (0,a_2)$, and $(a_1,a_2)$ (Cf. "The stabilized symplectic embedding problem for polydiscs" by D. Irvine p. 65)
What are the issue(s) with the corner $(a_1. a_2)$ in the moment description of $P(a_1 , a_2)$. I cannot find a reference describing this issue.
EDIT: I am interested in understanding the dynamics on the boundary of a polydisk. For ellipsoids, one can consider a (smooth) Reeb vector field along its boundary and characterize the dynamics by looking at the normal vector to its moment image. The issue with polydisks is that we cannot find a smooth vector field on its boundary. Thus the approach is to split its boundary into two pieces and consider two Reeb vector fields along each piece.

Your definition is not right.

That is why I am asking for the correct definition of a smooth point in this context.

I meant the definition of a polydisc. Why is $\pi$ in there and where are $a$ and $b$? It is the product of two disks, and this is not a manifold with boundary. I don't see how one would distinguish the point $(a,b)$ from any of the other points $(ae^{i\theta},be^{i\phi})$ on the boundary. This must be a very specialized use of the word "non-smooth."

The polydisc is regarded as a symplectic manifold and the constant $\pi$ is there so the symplectic area agrees with the area. My notation is probably confusing, when I say (a,b) it is supposed to be a point in the moment image.

(1/2) Ted Shifrin is right:  if $a$ and $b$ denote the radii of the polydisk $P(a,b)$, then we should read $$P(a,b)={ (z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : |z_1| \le a, |z_2| \le b }$$ ($a$ and $b$ needs to appear somewhere in the definition). Then the image of the moment map is a rectangle. I don't know where in Irvine's paper it is claimed that '$(a,b)$ is the only non-smooth point', but the non-smooth points of $P(a,b)$ are the preimages of the corner $(a,b)$ under the moment map, hence those $(z_1,z_2)$ of the form $(a e^{i\theta}, b e^{i \phi})$.

(2/2) A priori, the moment map is a surjective map $\mu : \mathbb{C}^2 \to [0, \infty)^2$. $\mu$ fails to be a submersion along the preimages of $[0, \infty) \times {0}$ and ${0} \times [0, \infty)$, i.e. along $\mathbb{C} \times {0}$ and ${0} \times \mathbb{C}$. Away from these sets, $\mu$ is a submersion, and so preimages of smooth hypersurfaces in $(0, \infty)^2$ are smooth hypersurfaces. For instance, the (boundary of the) ellipsoid is smooth, and indeed the part of its image under the moment map in $(0, \infty)^2$ is smooth.

Thanks for your comment. I get it know, the boundary of the polydisk is a smooth manifold with corners. In Irvine's paper he is considering Reeb orbits along the boundary of the polydisk, however, there is not a (smooth) Reeb vector field on the preimage $\mu^{-1}({a_1} \times [0,a_2] \cup [0,a_1] \times {a_2}) $. Thus, one should consider two Reeb vector fields: one along the horizontal side and another along the vertical side of the square.

You still have several mistakes in the post. "I've read that the only non-smooth point of the polydisc is the corner $(a_1,a_2)$" is wrong. (The correct statement is that the boundary of the polydisk is smooth away from $\mu^{-1}(a_1,a_2)$ and fails to be smooth at all points of   $\mu^{-1}(a_1,a_2)$.) Also, items 1 and 2 are wrong.

I edited my question, although, I now know the answer. I meant to say that $(a_1 , a_2)$ correspond to non-smooth points on the polydisk.
